# Why can't a switch send frames between two VLANs?

Tags: networking, switch

I only know the basics of networks.

Why can't a switch send frames between two VLANs? Or why can't a switch do broadcast on two different VLANs ?

Comment: What kind of switch are you asking about? Standard SOHO switches with basically no features?

Comment: Yeah I'm still new at this so probably soho switches

Answer (score 1):

If you physically connected two physically independent LANs to the same switch, they would become one big LAN. Same with VLANs. Bridging frames between two VLANs makes them one VLAN. It doesn't make sense to have multiple VLAN IDs for the same VLAN, so the switch management software doesn't provide a way to do it.

There are products with the misleading name of "Layer 3 switch" that really have built-in IP routing capabilities, so you can set up a virtual router to route between the two subnets on two VLANs. Routing at the IP layer is a proper way to allow connectivity between two VLANs.

You asked about just forwarding broadcasts, but the standards (like IEEE 802.1D) don't have provisions for bridges/switches that only forward broadcasts, and it would likely break things like ARP, DHCP, and IGMP.

Answer (score 1):

The basic purpose of the VLAN is to control the size of the
broadcast domain and to provide some separation between
groups of devices.

When you bridge VLANs together you merge the broadcast domains
and produce a single larger broadcast domain that removes
the separation between these groups of devices.

Most switches of at least a certain level of functionality
will keep memory tables that associate each node with one VLAN.
This allows the switch to limit a broadcast coming from a
specific node to its own VLAN, to reduce network congestion.